# Find linear factors for $1+x+y-(x+y)^2$

Tags: factoring

Can we find linear factors for the following polynomial with two variables?
$$1+x+y-(x+y)^2$$

**My Try**

First I tried writing two linear factors in general,
$$1+x+y-(x+y)^2=(Ax+By+C)(-\frac{1}{A}x-\frac{1}{B}y+\frac{1}{C})$$
During comparison of coefficients I ran into some trouble.

comparing xy terms:$ A=B$--(1)

comparing x terms: $AC=A^2-C^2$ --(2)

comparing y terms: $CB=B^2-C^2$--(3)

From (3)-(2) I get, $(B-A)(B+A)=(B-A)C$

from this point can I cancel (B-A) term from both sides? ( My guess is we can't because A=B) so how should I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think so there exist any linear factors because if you expand $(x+y)^2$ and then solve the expression, you get $$-x^2-2xy+x-y^2-y+1$$And from here, I don't see any factors

Comment: sorry there's a typo y should be plus editing it now

Comment: How would you factor $1+z-z^2$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin There exist no rational factors. Alpha shows that it can be factored over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$

Comment: @Algebrology ...which is no doubt real. Did you mean to say there are no _rational_ factors?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, Sorry, I meant rational

Comment: $$(\phi-x-y)(\phi^{-1}+x+y).$$

Comment: @Algebrology: you not seeing any factors does not prove that there aren't !

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's why I wrote "I don't **think** there exist any linear factors"

Comment: @Algebrology: expanding the polynomial is a bad idea, it hides the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not bad. We can restate the factorization with $a=b$ and we can also set WLOG $c=1$ (because $a,b,c$ are proportional). This gives

$$(ax+ay+1)\left(-\frac xa-\frac ya+1\right)=1+\left(a-\dfrac1a\right)x+\left(a-\dfrac1a\right)y-x^2-2xy-y^2=0.$$

Now it suffices to solve

$$a-\dfrac1a=1.$$

Anyway, it is much easier to factor $1+t-t^2$, as suggested by @Ivan.